# Tictactoe c program error with main function

Tags: c, syntax, syntax-error

I'm creating a simple tictactoe game in C. However I keep getting this error in my main function, I don't know what expected expression it wants before my else statement. How the program works is I get symbols from both players, an they begin the game.

**Error:**

```
tictac.c: In function ‘main’:
tictac.c:31: error: expected expression before ‘else’
tictac.c: At top level:
tictac.c:49: warning: conflicting types for ‘print’
tictac.c:30: warning: previous implicit declaration of ‘print’ was here
tictac.c:63: error: conflicting types for ‘check’
tictac.c:63: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
tictac.c:29: error: previous implicit declaration of ‘check’ was here
tictac.c:89: warning: conflicting types for ‘move’
tictac.c:28: warning: previous implicit declaration of ‘move’ was here
```

**Code:**

```
char board[3][3];

int main(void)
{
    int first;
    char player1, player2;

    printf("Player 1: Choose your symbol: \n");
    player1 = getchar();

    printf("Player 2: Choose your symbol: \n");
    player2 = getchar();

    int i=0;
    int win;
    char turn;
    while(win == 0)
    {
        if((i%2) == 0)
            turn = player1;
        move(player1);
        win = check(player1);
        print();
        else
            turn = player2;
        move(player2);
        i++;
    }

    if (i == 8)
        printf("its a tie");
    else
        printf("the winner is %c", turn);

    return 0;
}

/*printing the board that takes in a placement int*/
void print(void)
{
    int r;
    printf("\n");
    for (r = 0; r < 3; r++){
        printf(" %c | %c | %c \n" , board[r][0], board[r][2], board[r][3]);
        if (r != 2)
            printf("___________\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

/*check to see if someone won*/
int check(char player)
{
    int r, c;

    for ( r = 0 ; r <3 ; r++)
    {
        if ((board[r][0] == player) && (board[r][1] == player) && (board[r][2] == player))
            return 1;
    }

    for ( c = 0 ; c <3 ; c++)
    {
        if ((board[0][c] == player) && (board[1][c] == player) && (board[2][c] == player))
            return 1;
    }

    if((board[0][0] == player) && (board[1][1] == player) && (board[2][2] == player))
        return 1;

    if((board[0][2] == player) && (board[1][1] == player) && (board[2][0] == player))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

void move(char player)
{
    int place;
    printf("player1, enter placement: \n");
    scanf("%d", &place);

    if (place == 1)
        board[0][0] = player;
    else if (place == 2)
        board[0][1] = player;
    else if (place == 3)
        board[0][2] = player;

    else if (place == 4)
        board[1][0] = player;
    else if (place == 5)
        board[1][1] = player;
    else if (place == 6)
        board[1][2] = player;

    else if (place == 7)
        board[2][0] = player;
    else if (place == 8)
        board[2][1] = player;
    else if (place == 9)
        board[2][2] = player;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only omit the curly braces if you only have one line after if/else. Your error is here:

```
        if((i%2) == 0)
            turn = player1;
            move(player1);
            win = check(player1);
            print();
    else
            turn = player2;
            move(player2);
```

You need curly braces.  Also just a tip, at the bottom instead of 9 if statements, you could do something like this:

```
board[(place-1)/3][(place+2) % 3] = player;
```

and that should be equivalent to your 9 if statements in your move() function.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two categories of problems.

First, you need prototypes for your functions. Right below your `#include`s, but above your `int main(void)`, you'll want to include declarations (but not definitions) of your other functions:

```
void print(void);
int check(char player);
void move(char player);
```

This is necessary because C was designed such that it would be easy to compile it in one pass, going through the file. If the compiler doesn't know about those functions before they're used, you might have some problems.

Your second problem is that you're missing braces in a few places. Here, for example:

```
if((i%2) == 0)
    turn = player1;
    move(player1);
    win = check(player1);
    print();
else
    turn = player2;
    move(player2);
```

If an `if` statement (or a `for` or a `while` or a few other statements) needs to have multiple statements in its body, you must surround the body with braces:

```
if((i%2) == 0)
{
    turn = player1;
    move(player1);
    win = check(player1);
    print();
}
else
{
    turn = player2;
    move(player2);
}
```

The only reason it worked in other places, like here:

```
if (i == 8)
    printf("its a tie");
else
    printf("the winner is %c", turn);
```

…is that there's only a single statement: a call to `printf`. Multiple statements need braces.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in this piece of code

```
        if((i%2) == 0)
                turn = player1;
                move(player1);
                win = check(player1);
                print();
        else
                turn = player2;
                move(player2);        
        i++;
```

When you write more than one line of body in `control flow (if,else-if..)` or `iteration looping`, you have to put `{}` to define body.

Your code must be

```
 if((i%2) == 0){
                turn = player1;
                move(player1);
                win = check(player1);
                print();
       }
        else{
                turn = player2;
                move(player2); 
        }       
        i++;
```

Prototypes function must be declared for `print` ,`check` , `move`. Otherwise it'll take default prototype.